# Parsing large (9GB) file using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, large-files

I have a large text file that I need to parse into a pipe delimited text file using python. The file looks like this (basically):

```
product/productId: D7SDF9S9 
review/userId: asdf9uas0d8u9f 
review/score: 5.0 
review/some text here

product/productId: D39F99 
review/userId: fasd9fasd9f9f 
review/score: 4.1 
review/some text here
```

Each record is separated by two newline charters `/n`. I have written a parser below.

```
with open ("largefile.txt", "r") as myfile:
    fullstr = myfile.read()

allsplits = re.split("\n\n",fullstr)

articles = []

for i,s in enumerate(allsplits[0:]):

        splits = re.split("\n.*?: ",s)
        productId = splits[0]
        userId = splits[1]
        profileName = splits[2]
        helpfulness = splits[3]
        rating = splits[4]
        time = splits[5]
        summary = splits[6]
        text = splits[7]

fw = open(outnamename,'w')
fw.write(productId+"|"+userID+"|"+profileName+"|"+helpfulness+"|"+rating+"|"+time+"|"+summary+"|"+text+"\n")

return
```

The problem is the file I am reading in is so large that I run out of memory before it can complete. 
I suspect it's bambing out at the `allsplits = re.split("\n\n",fullstr)` line. 
Can someone let me know of a way to just read in one record at a time, parse it, write it to a file, and then move to the next record?

Comment: This looks like something that `sed` was made for.

Comment: Do you always have a colon before the data?  Your code makes me think so, but your last entry doesn't.  And can that last entry (text) encompass multiple lines?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't read the whole file into memory in one go; produce records by making use of those newlines. Write the data with the [`csv` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter) for ease of writing out your pipe-delimited records.

The following code reads the input file line at a time, and writes out CSV rows per record as you go along. It never holds more than one line in memory, plus one record being constructed.

```
import csv
import re

fields = ('productId', 'userId', 'profileName', 'helpfulness', 'rating', 'time', 'summary', 'text')

with open("largefile.txt", "r") as myfile, open(outnamename,'w', newline='') as fw:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(fw, fields, delimiter='|')

    record = {}
    for line in myfile:
        if not line.strip() and record:
            # empty line is the end of a record
            writer.writerow(record)
            record = {}
            continue

        field, value = line.split(': ', 1)
        record[field.partition('/')[-1].strip()] = value.strip()

    if record:
        # handle last record
        writer.writerow(record)
```

This code does assume that the file contains text before a colon of the form `category/key`, so `product/productId`, `review/userId`, etc. The part after the slash is used for the CSV columns; the `fields` list at the top reflects these keys.

Alternatively, you can remove that `fields` list and use a `csv.writer` instead, gathering the record values in a list instead:

```
import csv
import re

with open("largefile.txt", "r") as myfile, open(outnamename,'wb') as fw:
    writer = csv.writer(fw, delimiter='|')

    record = []
    for line in myfile:
        if not line.strip() and record:
            # empty line is the end of a record
            writer.writerow(record)
            record = []
            continue

        field, value = line.split(': ', 1)
        record.append(value.strip())

    if record:
        # handle last record
        writer.writerow(record)
```

This version requires that record fields are all present and are written to the file in a fixed order.

Comment: Hey Thanks! this looks good. I am getting this error when I use this method:  "csv.writerow(record); AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'writerow'" DO you know what my problem is?

Comment: @user2896837: that was a silly mistake on my part; corrected, it is `writer.writerow()`.

Comment: now I'm getting: "File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/csv.py", line 153, in writerow
    return self.writer.writerow(self._dict_to_list(rowdict))
TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface"

Comment: Ah, this is Python 3; adjusted the way the outputfile is opened for you.

Comment: sorry for so many questions. I'm annoying myself too. I'm getting this error: " File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/encodings/ascii.py", line 26, in decode return codecs.ascii_decode(input, self.errors)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xf8 in position 4146: ordinal not in range(128)" after I changed the way the output file is open. I've also tried encoding the string using ".encode('utf-8')", but no luck yet. Thanks again for your help and patience.

Comment: In Python 3, text files already return unicode; why are you trying to decode the data at all?

Comment: I'm not. I am getting this error using the code you have above. I was just trying to fix the error using encode/decode.

Comment: @user2896837: what encoding was used for the input file? You'll have to tell Python what to use: `open('hugeinputfile.txt', 'r', encoding='original codec') as myfile,`

Comment: Thank You! This is just a problem with my text file. It is tripping up on some weird character I think. I really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

Don't read the whole file into memory at once, instead iterate over it line by line, also use Python's [`csv` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) to parse the records:

```
import csv

with open('hugeinputfile.txt', 'rb') as infile, open('outputfile.txt', 'wb') as outfile:

    writer = csv.writer(outfile, delimiter='|')

    for record in csv.reader(infile, delimiter='\n', lineterminator='\n\n'):
        values = [item.split(':')[-1].strip() for item in record[:-1]] + [record[-1]]
        writer.writerow(values)
```

A couple things to note here:

- **Use `with` to open files**. Why? Because using `with` ensures that the file is `close()`d, even if an exception interrupts the script.

Thus:

```
with open('myfile.txt') as f:
    do_stuff_to_file(f)
```

is equivalent to:

```
f = open('myfile.txt')
try:
    do_stuff_to_file(f)
finally:
    f.close()
```

To be continued... (I'm out of time ATM)

Comment: This won't split off the record keys; you are writing `product/productId: D7SDF9S9` instead of `D7SDF9S9`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Ah, you're right! I overlooked that part.

Answer (score 0):

Use "readline()" to read the fields of a record one by one. Or you can use read(n) to read "n" bytes.