# Parse Text Files

Tags: parsing, text

I have very large text files which contain a lot of fluff which I want to remove. The text files come in two varieties, .txt and .csv. These files can be upwards as big as 200MB. For the past few years, I've been using VBA for Excel for parsing and statistical reporting and find it slow. Can someone point me to a solution for speed and novice friendly? No code requests yet, just looking for an alternative to parsing in Excel. Eventually, the final data file will be modified in Excel (statistical stuff). Thanks.

Tony
Hill-Rom

Comment: Check SQL Server Integration Services.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/23/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/

Answer (score 0):

A Novice Friendly scripting language able to parse / manipulate text quite easily would be Python in my opinion.

*I am not sure if such opinions should be explained on stack overflow but since you asked for ...*

I would use python, then you can find some inspiration from [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21653738/parsing-large-9gb-file-using-python)  which demonstrates a way to work on a very big size file.

Please give more details of what you want to do / which kind of data you want to work on if you need more details.