# How to read a large text file avoiding reading line-by-line :: Python

Tags: python, numpy, hdf5, h5py, numpy-memmap

I have a large data file (N,4) which I am mapping line-by-line. My files are 10 GBs, a simplistic implementation is given below. Though the following works, it takes huge amount of time.

I would like to implement this logic such that the text file is read directly and I can access the elements. Thereafter, I need to sort the whole (mapped) file based on column-2 elements.

The examples I see online assumes smaller piece of data (`d`) and using `f[:] = d[:]`but I can't do that since `d` is huge in my case and eats my RAM.

PS: I know how to load the file using `np.loadtxt` and sort them using `argsort`, but that logic fails (memory error) for GB file size. Would appreciate any direction.

```
nrows, ncols = 20000000, 4  # nrows is really larger than this no. this is just for illustration
f = np.memmap('memmapped.dat', dtype=np.float32,
              mode='w+', shape=(nrows, ncols))

filename = "my_file.txt"

with open(filename) as file:

    for i, line in enumerate(file):
        floats = [float(x) for x in line.split(',')]
        f[i, :] = floats
del f
```

Comment: If you can split the files, you might be able to use dask.

Comment: @user13815479 the `nrows, ncols` in your example represent 320 MB of data, which should easily fit in memory. How big is it really?

Comment: @James: Thanks, I am a newbie. Can you please elaborate more? If you can share a MWE, I would really appreciate that.

Comment: @Han-KwangNienhuys: That's just a simple example to show my logic. My text file is really large (10 GB) and N is large accordingly.

Comment: `loadtxt` (and `genfromtxt`) read csv files line by line, accumulating values in a list of lists (or arrays) which is converted to an array at the end.  `pandas` has a `c` based mode for its `pd.read_csv` which is faster - but the result is a dataframe.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21653738/parsing-large-9gb-file-using-python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: Instead of do-it-yourself chunking, it's better to use the chunking feature of pandas, which is much, much faster than numpy's `load_txt`.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

## create csv file for testing
np.random.seed(1)
nrows, ncols = 100000, 4
data = np.random.uniform(size=(nrows, ncols))
np.savetxt('bigdata.csv', data, delimiter=',')

## read it back
chunk_rows = 12345
# Replace np.empty by np.memmap array for large datasets.
odata = np.empty((nrows, ncols), dtype=np.float32)
oindex = 0
chunks = pd.read_csv('bigdata.csv', chunksize=chunk_rows, 
                     names=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])
for chunk in chunks:
    m, _ = chunk.shape
    odata[oindex:oindex+m, :] = chunk
    oindex += m

# check that it worked correctly.
assert np.allclose(data, odata, atol=1e-7)
```

The `pd.read_csv` function in chunked mode returns a special object that can be used in a loop such as `for chunk in chunks:`; at every iteration, it will read a chunk of the file and return its contents as a pandas `DataFrame`, which can be treated as a numpy array in this case. The parameter `names` is needed to prevent it from treating the first line of the csv file as column names.

#### Old answer below

The `numpy.loadtxt` function works with a filename or something that will return lines in a loop in a construct such as:

```
for line in f: 
   do_something()
```

It doesn't even need to pretend to be a file; a list of strings will do!

We can read chunks of the file that are small enough to fit in memory and provide batches of lines to `np.loadtxt`.

```
def get_file_lines(fname, seek, maxlen):
    """Read lines from a section of a file.
    
    Parameters:
        
    - fname: filename
    - seek: start position in the file
    - maxlen: maximum length (bytes) to read
    
    Return:
        
    - lines: list of lines (only entire lines).
    - seek_end: seek position at end of this chunk.
    
    Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63043614/6228891
    Copying: any of CC-BY-SA, CC-BY, GPL, BSD, LPGL
    Author: Han-Kwang Nienhuys
    """
    f = open(fname, 'rb') # binary for Windows \r\n line endings
    f.seek(seek)
    buf = f.read(maxlen)
    n = len(buf)
    if n == 0:
        return [], seek
    
    # find a newline near the end
    for i in range(min(10000, n)):
        if buf[-i] == 0x0a:
            # newline
            buflen = n - i + 1
            lines = buf[:buflen].decode('utf-8').split('\n')
            seek_end = seek + buflen
            return lines, seek_end
    else:
        raise ValueError('Could not find end of line')

import numpy as np

## create csv file for testing
np.random.seed(1)
nrows, ncols = 10000, 4

data = np.random.uniform(size=(nrows, ncols))
np.savetxt('bigdata.csv', data, delimiter=',')

# read it back        
fpos = 0
chunksize = 456 # Small value for testing; make this big (megabytes).

# we will store the data here. Replace by memmap array if necessary.
odata = np.empty((nrows, ncols), dtype=np.float32)
oindex = 0

while True:
    lines, fpos = get_file_lines('bigdata.csv', fpos, chunksize)
    if not lines:
        # end of file
        break
    rdata = np.loadtxt(lines, delimiter=',')
    m, _ = rdata.shape
    odata[oindex:oindex+m, :] = rdata
    oindex += m
    
assert np.allclose(data, odata, atol=1e-7)
```

Disclaimer: I tested this in Linux. I expect this to work in Windows, but it could be that the handling of '\r' characters causes problems.

Comment: Awesome! This seems to be working on a test 1GB file I have. Would appreciate if you can answer my specific questions: [1] odata = np.empty((nrows, ncols), dtype=np.float32) <= Any limit on nrows/ncols. I am afraid if that'd give me an error for really large (10-40 GB) files? [2] What is the for loop doing? Being a newbie, having a hard time in understanding. [3] So all the data is saved in odata and we are still consuming RAM, correct? Because on sorting "odata = odata[np.argsort(odata[:, 1])]"  I get a memory error for large file. Any suggestions to perform sorting?

Comment: Regarding [1] and [2]: I updated the answer. Regarding [3] on how to sort a large numpy memmap array: you need to post that as a new question if existing answers on that topic don't work for you.

Comment: Thanks, with your help I can read and store the data in HDF5, but I am unable to perform sorting on each chunk and produce a final (Nx4) array sorted on column-2. Any suggestions? I just asked the SO community as well.

Answer (score -1):

I realize this could not be an answer, but have you considered using binary files? When files are very large, saving in ascii is very un-efficient. If you can, use np.save and np.load instead.

Comment: Can you please elaborate more, considering I am a newbie? I basically have a large text file with 4 columns. You are saying converting that to binary file and then using np.load? Does that uses RAM? Would appreciate if you can share a MWE please?

Comment: Your answer is incomplete and should have been rather posted as a comment.