# Finding frequency of characters in a very large file

Tags: python, file-io

I have a text file that is ~4G big. I want to get the frequency of each character. Some lines start with a special character and they will be ignored. What is the fastest way to do this in python? I am trying the following:

```
import time
letters = {"A":0, "G": 0, "T":0, "C":0, "N":0}
count = 0
begin = time.time()
with open("dna_sequences.fa", 'rt') as f:
    for line in f:
        count += 1
        if count % 10000 == 0:
            end = time.time()
            print(count / 57478215, f"elapsed:{end-begin}s")


        if line.startswith(">"):
            continue
        l = line.strip().upper()
        for char in l:
            letters[char] += 1
```

It takes 12 seconds to parse 1% of the file. The file has `57478215` lines, as determined with `wc -l`. It would take 20+ minutes to parse the whole file. Is this the fastest way to do this?

Comment: Does this help you ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21653738/parsing-large-9gb-file-using-python (btw, good luck with that DNA)

Comment: @TheCodingPenguin Thanks! I suppose I'm already parsing it line-by-line, so unless we expect the csv module to speed things up, it won't be an improvement.

Comment: As a quick idea, maybe try counting the As just using your shell with `grep -v "^>" BIGFILE | tr -cd '[^A]' | wc -c` If that is fast, run 4 more in parallel for the other letters.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Yeah, that works, too. I just wanted to make sure I was doing the absolute best in python. Thanks!

Comment: Just out of interest, how long did it take?

Answer (score 1):

You could try to let compiled code do more work for you using the Counter class from collections.  Another optimization would be to count upper and lower case letters separately and add them up at the end (to avoid systematic upper/lower conversions on every line).

```
from collections import Counter

totals = Counter()
with open("dna_sequences.fa", 'rt') as f:
    for counts in map(Counter,f.readlines()):
        if not counts['>']:
            totals += counts
result = {c:totals[c]+totals[c.lower()] for c in "AGTCN"}

print(result)
{'A': 39999169, 'G': 39999411, 'T': 40004682, 'C': 39988262, 'N': 40008476}

# 12.8 seconds for 1 million lines (of 200 characters)
# would take roughly 12 minutes for the 57 million lines
```

*Note: this assumes that the '>' character only ever appears at the begining of a line (otherwise other lines may be excluded)*

If it weren't for the '>' lines you could do `totals = Counter(f.read())` in one operation and the time would go down to 9 seconds, so you may consider filtering the file beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

I can reduce the time by 40%, which is the result of an experiment with 270 MB of data.

```
from collections import Counter
import time

begin = time.time()
letters = Counter()
with open('example.txt', 'rt') as f:
    tuple(map(lambda x: '' if x.startswith('>') else letters.update(x.strip()), f.readlines()))
    
letters = {key: letters[key] + letters[key.lower()] for key in letters if key in {'A', 'T', 'C', 'G', 'N'}}
print(letters)
print(time.time() - begin)
```

```
{'C': 39991957, 'A': 39993241, 'G': 39982896, 'T': 39995691, 'N': 39987021}
12.470579862594604
```

.

```
begin = time.time()

letters = {"A":0, "G": 0, "T":0, "C":0, "N":0}
count = 0
with open("example.txt", 'rt') as f:
    for line in f:
        count += 1
        if line.startswith(">"):
            continue
        l = line.strip().upper()
        for char in l:
            letters[char] += 1
print(letters)
print(time.time() - begin)
```

```
{'A': 39993241, 'G': 39982896, 'T': 39995691, 'C': 39991957, 'N': 39987021}
21.683571100234985
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using spark. I had access to a node with many cores and a lot of memory, so I was able to do this.

Setup spark:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext

sc = SparkContext("local[*]", "test")
```

Read data:

```
data = sc.textFile("dna_sequences.fa")
# remove lines starting with >
seqs = data.filter(lambda x: not x.startswith(">"))
# create a set with each character
chars = seqs.flatMap(lambda x: [char for char in x])
# assing count of 1 to each character
keyvalue = aas.map(lambda x: (x,1))
# merge with keys (chars) to get count of each character
test = keyvalue.reduceByKey(lambda x,y: x+y)

# return counts of each character
chars = test.collect()
```